# Moment of Inertia of Wedge

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am yet to solve part (b). I have to use calculus, not a geometric method.

My (limited) working so far is:

$$dI = r^{2}\,dm\,dI = r^{2}\,dm$$

and

$$dI = r^{2}\,p\,dV\,dI = r^{2}\,p\,dV$$
In part (a), I could then rewrite $dV\,dV$ as $L\,dA\,L\,dA$ and so on in terms of $dr\,dr$, but I am not sure how to proceed in part (b)?.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use cartesian instead of polar coordinates.
Take $  Z $ axis along edge $ c $, $ X $ axis along $ b $ and $ Y $ axis parallel to $ a $ . Let $ \rho = 1 $.

$ dm = (c-{ \frac {c} {b} } x) dx dy $

$ dI_z = (x^2 + y^2) dm $

$ M = \frac {abc} {2} $

So $ I_z = \int_0^{a} \int_0^{b} (x^2+y^2) (c-{ \frac {c} {b} } x) dx dy $

Can check the end result by letting $ b =0 $ or $ a=0 $ to see if you get result for rectangular lamina or triangular lamina.